# How can I make selenium grab this href inside a tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

im currently trying to parse href from this website: https://jobs.gecareers.com/global/en/search-results?from=0&s=1

If you open the website, you should see a title for a job, click inspect element on it and you should see an A tag and href inside it, I am trying to the link and put it into a list.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

PATH = "D:\Criver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

LIST = []

driver.get(f'https://jobs.gecareers.com/global/en/search-results?from=0&s=1')
#links=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a.job_click")

elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "a.href"))
    )
for ele in elements:
    LIST.append(ele.text)

print(LIST)
```

Im not an expert at selenium but I've done work with it previously but for some reason I cant just get selenium to grab the href link inside the tag. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

USe `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`

```
job_link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('SAVED JOBS')
job_link.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your locator is wrong ifself and it is a css_selector, not ID.
Try this, it should work better

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[data-ph-at-id="job-link"]'))  
time.sleep(5)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a[data-ph-at-id="job-link"]')
for ele in elements:
    LIST.append(ele.text)

print(LIST)
```

The code above collects those elements texts. If you want to grab `href` values i.e. links, you should use this instead in the last code part:

```
for ele in elements:
    LIST.append(ele.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: It seems that it only appends the job title text from the HTML, though I did make some changes to it as it was not working for me (I use VSCODE). I added ) before time.sleep.

Comment: You need to add `LIST.append(ele.get_attribute('href'))` to get `href` along with text inside it

Comment: @cruisepandey Thanks! it was not clear what he is trying to get here

Comment: @JustinHoward I added the code to collect links